# differs in level of indirection from int 'int ()'

Tags: c

I'm building a linked list and I'm attempting to build a function to add a node, to test I pass through a name and size.

I think call it with my head but I get some strange error that I can't debug.

```
struct Test{
    char name[_MAX_NAME];
    int size;
    struct Test *next;
};

typedef struct Test *node;

node AddNode(node head, char name, int size);
```

in my Main

```
node head = NULL; // is this problem? 
head = AddNode(head,"Test Name",110);
```

> Error C2040   'AddNode': 'node (node,char,int)' differs in levels of
>   indirection from 'int ()'

Comment: what are`110` and `1` - which one is the `size` ?

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a change I attempted before and I forgot to edit. I fixed it

Comment: Function expects `char`, you are passing `char*`?

Comment: *but I get some strange error that I can't debug* -- what error?

Comment: Prime example of why you will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) -- which is never really a complete lesson without [Conversations:A Midsummer Night's Madness](http://www.drdobbs.com/conversationsa-midsummer-nights-madness/184403835) *"Confusion is the dark side of programming. Too many typedefs, poor naming choices — these all lead to..."*

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya from my understanding you suggesting that changing the function to except a char *? I attempted but same error. 

I'll attempt this same thing without typedef

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: No, it isn’t. The message “ 'node (node,char,int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'” suggests `AddNode` has a default declaration of `int AddNode()`, meaning OP omitted its declaration before using it, and the problem has nothing to do with type definitions or levels of indirection.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin excellent read btw, thank you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - right you are. The caution against typedeffing pointers notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the message “'node (node,char,int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'”. In this message, the `int ()` is the type one gets non-C-standard compilers from the default declaration that is provided when you do not declare a function. That is, when you use `AddNode` before its declaration, it is automatically declared as `int AddNode()`.

Then, later in your code when your declaration of `AddNode` appears, your declaration contrasts with the default declaration, and the compiler prints this message.

To fix this, put a declaration of `AddNode` before you use it. Such a declaration must appear in each source file where it is used. (Actually, the declaration must appear in the C *translation unit*, which means all the files that are included when you compile a source file. The translation unit includes header files that are included with `#include`. You must have a declaration of `AddNode` either in the source file itself or in a file it includes.)

Additionally, you declare `AddNode` as `node AddNode(node head, char name, int size);` but pass `"Test Name"` for the second parameter. As a function argument, `"Test Name"` acts as `char *`, not `char`, so you probably want to change the declaration to `node AddNode(node head, char *name, int size);`.